# getEmail() in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var project = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if (Session.getActiveUser.getEmail() == "mail1@gmail.com"){
    myfunc("sheet1");
  }
  if (Session.getActiveUser.getEmail() == "mail2@gmail.com"){
    myfunc("sheet2");
  }
  function myfunc(temp) {
    var values = project.getSheetByName(temp).getRange('H:H').getValues();
    var c = 0;
    while ( values[c] && values[c][0] != "" ) { c++; }
    project.getSheetByName(temp).setActiveRange(project.getSheetByName(temp).getRange(c+1,1));
  }
}
```

Есть 2 пользователя на одну таблицу, у каждого пользователя есть доступ к одному листу. Нужно чтоб скрипт автоматически перемещал фокус на первую пустую строку (проверка по колонке H). Перемещение работает, а вот фильтр по пользователю сообразить не могу

Comment: Разве это [StackOverfkow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)?

Comment: да вот я тоже чет попутал

Comment: Не получите вы имейл в простом триггере

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте про простые триггеры здесь - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions

Comment: Прочитал, спасибо.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос